# Double summation of matrix elements in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, matrix, sympy

Based on the simplified example below

[image]

I would like in my code

```
from sympy import*
import numpy as np
init_printing()

x, y = symbols('x, y')

mat = Matrix([[x,1],[1,y]])

X = [1, 2, 3]
Y = [[10, 20, 30], [40, 50, 60], [70, 80, 90]]
```

to substitute the symbolic `x` and `y` with values of `X` and `Y` and ofcourse calculate the double summation of the given matrix.

I'm trying to solve this but I'm having a rough time with the substitution in each step. 
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've imported both SymPy and NumPy, so you have a choice of tools here. And for the job of adding together a bunch of numeric matrices, numpy is the right tool. Here is how the summation happens in numpy:

```
sum([sum([np.array([[x,1], [1,y]]) for y in yr]) for x, yr in zip(X,Y)])
```

Here yr stands for a row of elements of Y. The outer sum is over i index, the inner is over j, although the list comprehension eliminates the need to spell them out.

The result is a NumPy array:

```
 array([[ 18,   9],
       [  9, 450]])
```

but you can turn it into a SymPy matrix just by putting `Matrix()` around it:

```
Matrix(sum([sum([np.array([[x,1], [1,y]]) for y in yr]) for x, yr in zip(X,Y)]))
```

Comment: Thank you, this works great. However in my case the matrix is larger and rewriting the lines does must be automated. Is there a way to do this for each row of the matrix without the need of rewriting every line inside the array?

Comment: I don't understand what "rewriting the lines" means.

Comment: Well you had to write [x,1], [1,y] and transform them into an array, but if the matrix is larger with, lets say, 10 lines, this wouldn't be practical as you would need to write all 10 lines inside the array... I was thinking if this could be done in a manner where the algorithm would do this for each line (row) without writing it inside the array... hopefully I made myself clear :)

Comment: Well, somehow it must be specified what the matrix is. If you have an algorithm by which its rows are computed, then define a function that accepts x,y as parametets and return a numpy array.