# Summing several equal size matrices by elements

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, matrix, sum

I've got a problem that I already opened and explained [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37468787/double-summation-of-matrix-elements-in-python). To be short, I need to replace the symbols in my analitically matrix with values and sum them all together. For better explanation I made the pic below:
[image]
Ofcourse there would be more matrices with bigger sizes.

However I've decided to approach this problem in a different way where I first saved all the different variations of my matrix in a larger array and from there on I vent on to summing them all together. This is my code so far:

```
from sympy import*
import numpy as np
init_printing()

T, logS = symbols('T, logS')
sig_izris = [[300,320,310],[410,435,440],[505, 515, 520]]
temperatura = [[500],[550],[600]]
Nap = np.asarray(np.log10(sig_izris))
Temp = []
for i in range(len(temperatura)):
    Temp.append(temperatura[i][0]+273.15) #Conversion to  Kelvin

def double_sum(mat, temp, nap):
    mat_12 = mat.subs(T, temp)
    mat_12 = mat_12.subs(logS, nap)
    return np.asarray(mat_12) 


test = Matrix([[logS, T, -1],[1, T**2, logS**2],[logS**3, T**2, 1]])
matrika = test
A = []
for i in range(len(Temp)):
    for j in range(len(Nap[i])):
        A.append(double_sum(matrika, Temp[i], Nap[i][j]))
mat_sum = sum(A)
mat_sum
```

But I'm not entirely convinced that my code is 100% correct or if the process could be optimized. 
I would like to know what is the correct way of summing several array by their elements. I've tried to use `add` from operator module and even `zip` but just didn't manage to write to correct code.

Comment: So you want to add several matrices element-wise? Your code does not appear to be a minimal example for that.

Comment: No it doesn't but that is why I added the link  to my original question. The code is made from 2 parts, in the first part I defined a function to replace the symbols from my matrix with actual values. In the second part I defined the matrix and saved every possible i-j combination by using the defined function in to array A. I think it isn't that hard to understand...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add several NumPy arrays of the same size element-wise as your hand-written formula shows you can simply write

```
M = M1 + M2 + M3
```

SymPy matrices are added similarly. You can mix and match the two:

```
import sympy
from sympy.abc import x
import numpy

A = sympy.Matrix([[x,0],[0,x]])
B = numpy.eye(2)
print A + B # Prints "Matrix([[x + 1.0, 0], [0, x + 1.0]])"
```

.

Comment: To really tell that you need a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. The code in your question has bad indentation but it also doesn't work after you fix it. (E.g., `T` is not defined.)

Comment: Sorry about that, I fixed it.

Comment: Yes, in the updated code `sum(A)` does add the matrices in it. You can verify that by printing `A` before `sum(A)`.